# How to migrate Docker data with configured (data) postgresql with configured data... to another machine and load the configured data

Tags: postgresql, docker

I've created a docker image with postgres 12.14 and a table with pgadmin; so I used the following commands to migrate the docker data:

```
wsl --shutdown   
wsl --export docker-desktop-data C:\test\dockerdesk.tar
```

I copied the dockerdesk.tar and I moved this to my another computer with a USB.
Then, I used the following commands,
I used this on another device with installed docker:

```
wsl --shutdown 
wsl--unregister docker-desktop-data
wsl --import docker-desktop-data C:\test C:\test\dockerdesk.tar
```

Then I turned on docker by opening the docker application, and I run the following command:

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234 -p 5432:5432 -d postgres:12.14
```

then when I connected to pgadmin and I can connect to the Postgres but there was no table I created previously,so It was not working well.
What could It be wrong, could you help me, please?
I did the above commands and I was expecting the first table I created in the first device.